# Ideal Strategy to maximise write throughput of RDD in cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I have a 3 Node cluster on same DC and same rack. Keyspace has Replication Factor with 2, I have a spark application which is taking data form Kafka and Now I'am saving the RDD to Cassandra with

```
rdd.saveToCassandra("db_name", "table_name")
```

I'm consuming with Time interval of 10 Seconds and every batch will have 10k records and size per batch is around 2.5 MB

In Spark Conf I have setup

```
.set("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "ONE")
```

Application takes around 2-3 seconds to insert. Why so? I would like to optimise. Earlier when I was using 1 Node machine with RF-1 , I was able to insert at a rate of 0.8-1 second/ batch. So, why this much delay after increase in node and RF.

Is there any other setting do I need to make in Spark Conf or cassandra side to increase write speed.